# PHP/MySQL COUNT doesn't seem to work as it should

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm pulling my hair out for this, what is wrong with this query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(id), * 
    FROM location 
   WHERE country = '$country' 
     AND LCASE(namenodiacritics) LIKE LCASE('%$locname%') 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Am I allowed to COUNT(id) and * in a single query?

I keep getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM location WHERE country = 'AQ' AND LCASE(namenodiacritics) LIKE LCASE('%%'' at line 1

The weird thing is that it works with "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM..." and also "SELECT * FROM...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `COUNT()` without `GROUP BY` reduces the result to a single row. You can't get meaningful values in the rest of the columns that way.

You can do it in two queries:

```
  -- this returns a single row
  SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM location 
   WHERE country = '$country' 
     AND LCASE(namenodiacritics) LIKE LCASE('%$locname%');

  -- this returns multiple rows, one per matching location    
  SELECT *
    FROM location 
   WHERE country = '$country' 
     AND LCASE(namenodiacritics) LIKE LCASE('%$locname%')
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Selecting `COUNT(id)` and `*` in the same query doesn't make sense. If you really need to get all of the other fields, then just use '`SELECT * FROM ...`' and it is easy enough to get the number of rows returned using PHP.

Comment: Performing the count in the database will always be faster than PHP/etc.

Comment: @rexem - in this case probably not.  The only way to do what the OP wants is to do two queries.  mysql_num_rows() on the resultset from one query will be faster than two queries.

Comment: On the smallest of result sets, PHP/etc ***might*** be on par with what any database can do. But that approach won't scale as data increases. Those that recommend this approach are usually those who know/use SQL the least if at all.

Comment: @rexem - completely wrong.  mysql_num_rows() will get the size of the resultset (what the OP wants, here) in O(1) time.  Are you claiming that doing a subquery is better than O(1)?

Comment: @tim: It's your claim, you prove it.

Comment: @tim: The `mysql_num_rows()` function only provides the row count *after* you have fetched all the rows from the server.  So you either fetch implicitly on execute by using a buffered query, or else you have to fetch all the rows yourself and then count them.  Neither of these are O(1) operations.

Comment: @bill I'm assuming based on the OP's stuff that he's already going to be fetching all the rows, ie: using plain old mysql_query or equivalent.  If that assumption holds, then mysql_num_rows() should give him the size of his result set in O(1).  Now, since OP wants pagination, he'd be way better off with a subquery and LIMIT.  But given the implementation implied, mysql_num_rows will give him what he wants with less overhead.  Unless I'm missing something else, which is possible.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to count?

Hint: You should probably be using grouping by something if you're using an aggregate function like COUNT()

Comment: I'm trying to get all the data from locations table (a location is a particular place in the world) and also get the total count so I can split the results over multiple pages (there's a huge number in US).

Comment: Then you need two queries, either two distinct, or a subquery.  COUNT() is an aggregate function, so it needs to be used with a GROUP BY clause.  The COUNT() for each row will represent how many rows are grouped together.

Comment: (the exception is a "SELECT COUNT(column) FROM table" type query, where the grouping is implicit.

Comment: @tim: I don't know what you mean by the grouping is implicit.  Using COUNT() without GROUP BY treats the whole set of matching rows as a single group, so the output is a single row.

Comment: @bill - correct.  using count() without GROUP BY does indeed (implicitly) treat the whole set as a single group.

Comment: @tim: Okay cool.  I just didn't know if you thought it would automatically create groups based on the column argument to the COUNT() function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
  SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM location) as cnt, * 
    FROM location 
   WHERE country = '$country' 
     AND LCASE(namenodiacritics) LIKE LCASE('%$locname%') 
ORDER BY name ASC
```